# Maven Create Jar and exclude Files

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I am trying to create a runnable Jar file. I have to create a Jar of only one single java class (`MyClass` which is under the folder structure  `src/main/java/org/miso/mcs/util/MyClass`) and exclude others. I am able to create to JAR but it has everything.

I am using `mvn clean package assembly:single` command to create Jar.

```xml
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <descriptorRefs>
      <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
    </descriptorRefs>
    <archive>
      <manifest>
        <mainClass>org.miso.mcs.util.MyClass</mainClass>
      </manifest>
    </archive>  
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <classesDirectory>src/main/java/org/miso/mcs/util</classesDirectory>
        <includes>
          <include>/*MyClass*</include>
        </includes>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>/*</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </resource>
    </resources>               
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to do that by using the predefined [`jar-with-dependencies`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/descriptor-refs.html#jar-with-dependencies) descriptor. However, we can make our own assembly descriptor for that:

```xml
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.3" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.3 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.3.xsd">
  <id>jar-with-dependencies</id>
  <formats>
    <format>jar</format>
  </formats>
  <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
  <dependencySets>
    <dependencySet>
      <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
      <useProjectArtifact>false</useProjectArtifact>
      <unpack>true</unpack>
    </dependencySet>
    <dependencySet>
      <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
      <useProjectArtifact>false</useProjectArtifact>
      <useProjectAttachments>true</useProjectAttachments>
      <includes>
        <include>${project.groupId}:${project.artifactId}:jar:classes:${project.version}</include>
      </includes>
      <unpack>true</unpack>
      <unpackOptions>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>%regex[org\/miso\/(?!mcs\/util\/MyClass).*]</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </unpackOptions>
    </dependencySet>
  </dependencySets>
</assembly>
```

[`unpackOptions`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html#class_unpackOptions) allows to control the content the unpacked dependencies in the JAR. In this case, we are excluding everything under the `org.miso` package (which I assume are the classes of your project) and we're only including the class you're interested in (`org.miso.mcs.util.MyClass`). This will result in a runnable JAR with only the specified class of your project.

Since your project is a WAR, it is a little more complicated. The first dependency set declares all the dependencies of the project and unpacks them. The second only uses the projects attachments and includes only the `classes` attachment built by the `maven-war-plugin`.

If you save that snippet into a file called `assembly.xml` located under `src/assembly`, your POM will then look like:

```xml
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.6</version>
  <configuration>
    <attachClasses>true</attachClasses>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.6</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>make-assembly</id>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>single</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <descriptors>
          <descriptor>src/assembly/assembly.xml</descriptor>
        </descriptors>
        <archive>
          <manifest>
            <mainClass>org.miso.mcs.util.MyClass</mainClass>
          </manifest>
        </archive>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

With such a configuration, you just need to invoke Maven with `mvn clean install` and it will correctly generate the JAR. Then, you can launch that JAR with `java -jar name-of-jar.jar`.

Comment: Thank you Tunaki for your help.